# django-webpack points to localhost in production

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack

I use vue and django webpack loader for rendering a vue app in django template.

it works well locally, but when I deploy it, it goes all wrong

In template I have this:

```
    {% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
    {% render_bundle "chunk-vendors" %}
    {% render_bundle "app" %}
```

which in production is rendered like that:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/js/app.js" ></script>
```

The `vue.config.js` looks like that:

```
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const path = require('path');

const DEPLOYMENT_PATH = '/static/dist'

module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? DEPLOYMENT_PATH : 
    'http://localhost:8080/',
    outputDir: '../_static/dist',

    configureWebpack: {
        
        plugins: [
            new BundleTracker({path: __dirname, filename: 'webpack-stats.json'}),
        
        ],
    },
    "transpileDependencies": [
        "vuetify"
    ],
    chainWebpack: config => {
       
          config.resolve.alias
            .set('__STATIC__', 'static');

        config.devServer
            .public('http://localhost:8080')
            .host('localhost')
            .port(8080)
            .hotOnly(true)
            .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
            .https(false)
            .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    },
}

``
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation.... using process.env.XXX solved mine....

`DEPLOYMENT_PATH=MY_COOL_PATH npm run build --prefix frontend/`

```
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
const path = require('path');

const DEPLOYMENT_PATH = '/static/dist'

module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.DEPLOYMENT_PATH : 
    'http://localhost:8080/',
    outputDir: '../_static/dist',

    configureWebpack: {
        
        plugins: [
            new BundleTracker({path: __dirname, filename: 'webpack-stats.json'}),
        
        ],
    },
    "transpileDependencies": [
        "vuetify"
    ],
    chainWebpack: config => {
       
          config.resolve.alias
            .set('__STATIC__', 'static');

        config.devServer
            .public('http://localhost:8080')
            .host('localhost')
            .port(8080)
            .hotOnly(true)
            .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
            .https(false)
            .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    },
}

``
```